# Hide 'Connect To Outlook' button from Calendar Tab Ribbon (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: ribbon, outlook

How can I, via a feature, hide the 'Connect To Outlook' button from the 'Connect & Export' group in the 'Calendar' tab when I view a calendar on a SharePoint 2010 site?

I have tried several variations, none of them work. What is the correct XML for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <HideCustomAction
      Location="Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions"
      HideActionId="ConnectToClient">
    </HideCustomAction>
</Elements>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <HideCustomAction
      Location="Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions"
      HideActionId="Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions.ConnectToClient">
    </HideCustomAction>
</Elements>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <HideCustomAction
      Location="Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions.Controls"
      HideActionId="Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions.ConnectToClient">
    </HideCustomAction>
</Elements>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <HideCustomAction
      Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
      Location="Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions.ConnectToClient">
    </HideCustomAction>
</Elements>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <CustomAction
          Id="Remove.Calendar.ConnectToClient"
          Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
            <CommandUIExtension>
                <CommandUIDefinitions>
                    <CommandUIDefinition
                      Location="Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions.ConnectToClient" />
                </CommandUIDefinitions>
            </CommandUIExtension>
        </CustomAction>
    </Elements>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <CustomAction
          Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
          Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
            <CommandUIExtension>
                <CommandUIDefinitions>
                    <CommandUIDefinition
                      Location="Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions.ConnectToClient" />
                </CommandUIDefinitions>
            </CommandUIExtension>
        </CustomAction>
    </Elements>
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [Connect to Outlook – Tipps und Tricks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointalps/sharepoint-2010-connect-to-outlook-tipps-und-tricks) ([English version](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointalps/sharepoint-2010-connect-to-outlook-tipps-und-tricks&ei=WYh6TYTlL-Pj0gGUzv3WAw&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=32&ved=0CPgBEO4BMB8&prev=/search?q=sharepoint%20ConnectToClient&num=100&hl=en&safe=active&sa=X&biw=866&bih=502&nfpr=1&prmd=ivnsfdb)), it looks like you want something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
      Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
      Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
      RegistrationType="List"
      RegistrationId="106">
        <CommandUIExtension>
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIDefinition
                  Location="Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions.ConnectToClient" />
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
        </CommandUIExtension>
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Comment: This is the best way idd

Answer (score 0):

Really simple to hide the item using a stylesheet.  Determine the Connect to Outlook button ID using the F-12 developer bar.

In my case, it has an ID of

```
Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions-LargeMedium-0-0
```

(decimal points and colons are valid in ID names.  Not sure why, but the W3C allows them)

Stylesheet syntax (since ID name contain decimal points) will be

```
[id='Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions-LargeMedium-0-0'] {display:hide !important;}
```

Apply the stylesheet in a CEWP, et voila.  Note that this affects all users.